# SpringBoot RabbitMQ configuration in kubernetes (minikube)

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, rabbitmq, minikube

I have created a simple springboot rest api that will send message in rabbitmq. I want to configure it in minikube. So I created the below configuration

1. rabbit service

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     creationTimestamp: null
     name: rabbit
   spec:
     type: NodePort
     ports:
      - name: http
        protocol: TCP
        port: 15672
        targetPort: 15672
      - name: amqp
        protocol: TCP
        port: 5672
        targetPort: 5672
     selector:
       run: rabbit
   status:
     loadBalancer: {}
   #---
   #---
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     creationTimestamp: null
     labels:
       run: rabbit
     name: rabbit
   spec:
     containers:
     - image: rabbitmq:management
       name: rabbit
       ports:
       - containerPort: 5672
       - containerPort: 15672
       resources: {}
     dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
     restartPolicy: Never
   status: {}
   ```
2. Springboot application service yaml

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     creationTimestamp: null
     name: message
   spec:
     type: NodePort
     ports:
      - name: http-message
        protocol: TCP
        port: 8081
        targetPort: 8081
     selector:
       run: message
   status:
     loadBalancer: {}
   #---
   #---
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
     creationTimestamp: null
     labels:
       run: message
     name: message
   spec:
     containers:
     - image: <my-spring-boot-image>
       name: message
       ports:
       - containerPort: 8081
       resources: {}
   status: {}
   ```
3. Springboot application.properties

```
server.port=8081
message.amqp.queue=message-queue
message.amqp.exchange=message-queue-exchange
message.amqp.host=rabbit
message.amqp.bind=message.#
message.amqp.route=message.queue
```

4. My kubernetes objects are as bellow:

```
$ kubectl get all
NAME                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/rabbit          1/1     Running   0          45m
pod/message         1/1     Running   0          34m

NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                          AGE
service/rabbit          NodePort    10.107.247.31   <none>        15672:31254/TCP,5672:31632/TCP   45m
service/message         NodePort    10.97.211.105   <none>        8081:30549/TCP                   34m
service/kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                          42d
```

When I send message to the rest API, it cannot connect to rabbit, as lt was still trying to connect to **localhost**. I am getting below error

```
2021-06-16 21:59:46.631  INFO 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2021-06-16 21:59:46.693 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

How can I configure springboot to connect to the rabbitmq host in minikube environment?

**P.S. I do not want to use helm charts**

Comment: We built a RabbitMQ  operator for Kubernetes https://github.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator We suggest to use it.

Comment: @GabrieleSantomaggio Thanks. Let me dig into it.